# Auto mapper - Mapping objects with collections

Tags: c#, automapper

using Auto Mapper, I need to Map objects of following classes

```
public class RemoteClass
{
    public IEnumerable<RemoteDetails> collection{get; set;};

    public int RemoteFieldA{get; set;}

    public int RemoteFieldB{get; set;}      
}


public class LocalClass
{
    public IEnumerable<LocalDetails> collection{get; set;};

    public int LocalFieldA{get; set;}

    public int LocalFieldB{get; set;}       
}
```

What should be my configration and mapping for this ?

Comment: What is RemoteDetails and LocalDetails? What have you tried so far? What problems you have with your mapping?

Comment: classes, i have edited to include "class". The part I am not sure about is how to Map Collections from both these classes.

Comment: I am able to Map RemoteFieldA with LocalFieldA and RemoteFieldB with LocalFieldB which was very simple. However, I am not sure what should I do to map collection from RemoteClass to collection from LocalClass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just define mapping between `RemoteDetails` and `LocalDetails`. AutoMapper is smart enough to deal with collections of types which he knows how to map. Assume these two classes have field C:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RemoteDetails, LocalDetails>()
      .ForMember(ld => ld.LocalFieldC, opt => opt.MapFrom(rd => rd.RemoteFieldC));

Mapper.CreateMap<RemoteClass, LocalClass>()
      .ForMember(lc => lc.LocalFieldA, opt => opt.MapFrom(rc => rc.RemoteFieldA))
      .ForMember(lc => lc.LocalFieldB, opt => opt.MapFrom(rc => rc.RemoteFieldB));
```

With these mappings you can map from RemoteClass to LocalClass:

```
RemoteClass remote = new RemoteClass {
    RemoteFieldA = 42,
    RemoteFieldB = 100,
    collection = new [] { 
        new RemoteDetails { RemoteFieldC = "Foo" },
        new RemoteDetails { RemoteFieldC = "Bar" }
    }
};

var local = Mapper.Map<LocalClass>(remote);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: didn't know its this simple. Thanks for your prompt help :)